# Overwrite event - data from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql, update

In MySQL is it possible to execute an update query with values selected from external SQL Server database?

I'd like to execute every night a timed query, which overwrites some data in MySQL with data on SQL Server.

Comment: You should show use the table structure of the table in SQL Server you are sourcing from and the table structure of the table you are updating with the data from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Write PHP/Perl/Java/VB/whatever code to `SELECT` from one db server and `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/whatever into the other.

For "timed", use cron (if on *nix).